# Regular Expression on PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem in splitting a string using regex.

I have searched about regex to split string on uppercase word, but what I need is to split string like in the following example.

Having this example data:

```
This is First SentenceThis is Second Sentence
```

... the string should be split like this:

```
This is First Sentence
This is Second Sentence
```

Anyone know the solution for this?

Comment: So you want to split when Uppercase letter occurs in a word like `SentenceThis` ?

Comment: So, the splitting point is "an uppercase letter directly after anything other than a whitespace"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`\K`**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#bsk) token combined with a [lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) assertion.

```
$str = 'This is First SentenceThis is Second Sentence';
$results = preg_split('~[a-z]\K(?=[A-Z])~', $str);
print_r($results);
```

Or utilize both look-behind and lookahead assertions:

```
$results = preg_split('~(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])~', $str);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is First Sentence
    [1] => This is Second Sentence
)
```

Comment: wow this works.. thanks.. :) However what '~' and '\K' means?

Comment: `~` is used as the pattern delimiters here.

Comment: This approach is good if input does not have CaMeL words at the end/start of the sentence. Consider "I have an iPodIt is my father's present." Thus, regex can only help with the task in part.

Comment: If you want this to work for any language, you can use Unicode properties like this: `(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})`